# Is the template used when creating a new crontab stored centrally, or embedded into the cron package?

Tags: command-line, cron

When choosing to create a new crontab for a user by using the "crontab -e" command within a terminal, I've noticed that some kind of default template appears to be used that explains the functionality of each field within the crontab file. Is this template stored centrally - or part of the cron package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard-coded into the `crontab.c` file in the cron package's source code:

```
        if (add_help_text) {
                fprintf(NewCrontab,
"# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.\n"
"# \n"
"# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line\n"
"# indicating with different fields when the task will be run\n"
"# and what command to run for the task\n"
"# \n"
"# To define the time you can provide concrete values for\n"
"# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),\n"
"# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any')."
"# \n"
"# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system\n"
"# daemon's notion of time and timezones.\n"
"# \n"
"# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through\n"
"# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).\n"
"# \n"
"# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts\n"
"# at 5 a.m every week with:\n"
"# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/\n"
"# \n"
"# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)\n"
"# \n"
"# m h  dom mon dow   command\n" );
        }
```